# Dynamically create html components in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning

Since HTML tags are first class citizens in lightning is there a way to instantiate them as components in lightning? Something like:

```
    $A.createComponent(
        "html:div",
        {
            "aura:id": "test1",
            "textContent": "test"
        },
        function(div){
            //Add the new button to the body array
            var container = cmp.find("container");
            if (container.isValid()) {
                var body = container.get("v.body");
                body.push(div);
                container.set("v.body", body);
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: you can create dynamically lightning component https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm

Comment: Thanks, I am aware that lighting components can be dynamically created, but I get an internal error if I try and create html elements. The docs say html elements are first class citizens but it doesn't appear that they can be created using createComponent like any other lighting component

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
$A.createComponent(
    "aura:html",
     { 
         tag: "div",
         HTMLAttributes:{"id": "Temp","class": "class name here"}
     },
     function(compo){
          var container = cmp.find("container");
          if (container.isValid()) {
              var body = container.get("v.body");
              body.push(compo);
              container.set("v.body", body);
          }
     }
);
```

Comment: It works, but my goodness is that ever chatty.

Comment: And if you dont want to use jquery?