# Why i can't access my <iframe> in Lightning?

Tags: lightning, iframe, lightning-renderer

Im trying to manipulate my iframe from the renderer but i can't get to the Document of the Iframe.

Component:

```
<aura:component access="global" implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId">
    <iframe aura:id="FileFrame" src="about:blank" style="width:100%;height:500px"></iframe>
</aura:component>
```

Renderer:

```
({
    afterRender: function(component, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getMyVFpageA");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            console.log('hiaudsilhudas');
            var doc = component.find("FileFrame").getElement().contentDocument;
            console.log(doc);
            doc.open();
            doc.write('<html><head><title></title></head><body>Hello world.</body></html>');
            doc.close();
            });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);}
})
```

Comment: any errors in the  browser's console or network tab? please update your post if any.

Comment: did you try `contentWindow.document` (not sure here as I got it from a SO answer) after `getElement` or add a regular Id to the iframe and use: `document.getElementById('iFrameId').contentDocument;`

Comment: The [Locker Service documentation](http://documentation.auraframework.org/lockerApiTest/secureElement.app?aura.mode=DEV) lists `contentDocument` as **Not To Be Supported** for iframes.

Comment: See https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/122250 for a method for generating HTML dynamically in Lightning. You can't use an iframe.

Comment: Thanks everyone, ive done some more testing and i think there with lockerservice and clickjackprotection for VF Pages there is no way to achive this.