# div element not found while using $A.createComponent

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, create-component

I am trying to create a div using $A.createComponent but its throwing error.

```
`$A.createComponent("aura:HTML",
        { 
            "tag": "div",
            "HTMLAttributes":{"id": "filter-"+ component.get('v.index') +"", "Text":"Test"},
            "class":""
        },
        function(result, status, errorMessage){
             if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                $A.createComponents(components,
                                    function(components, status, errorMessage){
                                         if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                                           var divElement = document.getElementById("filter-" + component.get("v.index"));
                                           //var divElement = component.find(component.get('v.targetDiv'));
                                           console.log('Div element');
                                           var elementBody = divElement.get("v.body");
                                         }
                                     } 
                                    );
                       } 
         }
       );
```

Please ignore if any missing brackets are there I may have made mistake while copying it. 
It throws that divElement does not have get method or divElement is undefined.
I know that component.find(component.get('v.index')) is trying to assign some value which never exist. 
how can I over come this situation?

Comment: No i have not assigned it. let me do that. What difference does it make? Can you please explain me?

Comment: I think problem in creating  html tag , refer this link https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/122250/dynamically-create-html-components-in-lightning

Comment: Thanks for the link but. I want to add my data in the particular div. I already referred the link which you provided. 
Means I want to push my result in that div..

Comment: The div element that you have created is an HTML element and not a lightning or aura element. As a result it does not have a method such as `get('v.body')`. I believe when the error occurs on this line, the JS stops executing further and the element does not appear on your lighting component.

Comment: yes it may be the reason. How can add the result to the div?
But in developer tool the divElement it self shows undefined.

Answer (score 2):

`$A.createComponent` does **not** actually put the element in the DOM anywhere. `result` in your code is the div that was created, but you still need to put it somewhere.

In your second callback, you could refer to it directly:

```
result.set("v.body", components);
```

But don't forget to place it back into your component's body:

```
component.set("v.body", result);
```

Comment: I found the solution but thats not the direct or simple one.